# ajax error with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am using the following function which has worked fine up until now, but I am frequently getting the following error:

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://www.myURL.info/manage/sharedLibrary.js :: getFile :: line 406"  data: no]

**NOTE** error line is indicated below directly after comment in code block.

**ADDITIONAL RESEARCH** this is apparently a common issue with firefox. 
Does anyone have a cleaner way to do [this]?[1](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_a_1.html)

The function has worked perfectly up until now and is as follows:

```
function getFile(url){
    var AJAX = null;
    try{
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            AJAX = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if(AJAX){
            AJAX.open("GET", url, false);
            //The line below is line 406 in the error code.
            AJAX.send(null);
            return AJAX.responseText;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }catch(err){
        var a = prompt("", err);
    }
}
```

I am using firefow as my browser. if I crash Firefox and relaunch the error is no longer present yet does resurface after a bit of time. The use case is not totally precise.

Is there some variable I should be resetting with each request?

If I try and catch, the error seems to break some underlying functionality that is not reset until the browser is relaunched.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is apparently the line that is causing the error (406): `AJAX.send(null);`. If the error gives a line number, it's usually a good idea to point out which line and/or what is on that line in the question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is in the comments of the code above. it is the AJAX.send(null).

Comment: Oh. Maybe make it more obvious, as in in the text before the code block say *See commented line for relevant line of code*? i just totally didn't see it, and I looked several times.

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry! point taken. ill give a heads up.

Comment: A cleaner way to do this? jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AJAX.onreadystatechange = function(){ var text = AJAX.responseText};
```

before

```
AJAX.send(null);
```